# React Native: Are there reasons that it will run slower on Android than iOS?

Tags: android, react-native

I know this is a general question but I could not get any existing satisfactory answer/explanation, so posting here hoping that someone can help me out.

I am developing an RN app and when run from actual devices, it runs much slower on Android devices (3-4x). Specifically, each of the pages takes longer to load across the board for the array of Android devices compared to iPhones. So this doesn't have something to do with Hermes, which is about initial startup time and which I have implemented already.

Potential reasons I thought of are: a) Code hasn't been optimized, b) Android devices are inherently slower. But while it's true that my code hasn't been fully optimized, it still runs pretty fast on iPhones. Also, I tested on the lastet models of Android phones, so it is hard to believe that there are hardware performance differences that warrant 3-4x differences in loading speed for pretty much every part of my app.

Existing answers mention getting rid of console.log() statements and disabling dev mode, but there is zero console.log() statement in my app and I am testing a production build from Android devices.

Are there valid reasons to believe that RN will run slower on Android in certain cases? e.g. because of the way Android works or the way RN interacts with the native module, some optimization issues bite much harder on Android? Where should I start to debug this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did your app run way slower on emulator or on physical device?
Which actions take longer?

Comment: @MichaelBahl, the app runs even slower on emulator. I'd say it runs 1.5x slower on emulator than on actual Android device. But I suppose Android emulators are indeed slow. Slow performance in actual Android devices are the real issues for the users. Among the app's actions, loadings of the components are slow across the board, so I assume there is an underlying issue that I don't know.

Comment: Unnecessary rerender might be the root cause for the performance issue.

Usually iPhones are more powerful than android devices which could lead to incorrect conclusion that the performance issue is caused by the operating system.

You can detect these rerenders with react native dev tools Profiler.

Comment: @MichaelBahl, thanks for the reply. Do you mean that unnecessary rerenders hit harder for Android phones? What do you mean by 'more powerful'? Do you mean the pure computing power or that iOS somehow dampens effects from unnecessary rerenders?

Comment: yes that ist what I mean.